# PyQt: Qtablewidget itemClick

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a **Qtablewidget** , it connects **itemClick slot**.             **tab_item_one_click_event** is an one click slot function，not double click slot function.

```
self.tab = QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.tab.itemClicked.connect(self.tab_item_one_click_event)
```

I find two problem

1. If this item text is not empty,double click also run slot function.I want slot function to be executed by one click.
2. If this item text is empty  and I double click item twice,the slot function will run.The first one click  is useless.

The first problem I guess I can write one_click signal function to  solve it.Maybe I can judge two clicks time.But if `QtableWidget` have other functions is better.
The second problem  I don't know  the reason.

Update:
The second problem I use space to initialize item text.So my first click will be useful ，although item is still empty.But why I have to initialize item text ,the signal function will work,I don't know the reason.

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(" ")
self.tab.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Comment: Qtabwidget or QTableWidgetItem?

Comment: @eyllanescSorry,it'is QTableWidgetlem, I have corrected my problem

Comment: QTableWidgetItem does not have the itemclicked signal, this has QTableWidget

Comment: @eyllanesc I know QTableWidge document does not have the itemclicked signal, QListWidget has . But  when I use pycharm automatic complete function, I can see itemClicked is QTableWidget function.And I execute my program ,there is no error here.

Comment: change `self.tab = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()` to `self.tab = QtGui.QTableWidget()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I think I need a good sleep,I am now a piece of paper paste.Sorry , my wrong question waste you free time.